# using psql environment in a function declaration

Tags: variables, psql

I am failing to use a parameter in function declaration.

a SQL script like :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_functon() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  test int:=:SRID;
BEGIN
  RETURN NEW;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

in a file.

And running `psql -v SRID=2056 -f my_file.sql`

leads to the error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"

This looks like the SQL is run without the var being properly replaced by its value.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like psql does not interpolate variables in the body of functions.

The following SQL verifies that.

```
SELECT :SRID;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_functon() RETURNS :TYPE AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN :SRID;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Running that file results in this:

```
$ psql -v SRID=2056 -v TYPE=int -f query.sql
Expanded display is used automatically.
Null display is "¤".
 ?column?
----------
     2056
(1 row)

psql:query.sql:9: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4:   RETURN :SRID;
                 ^
```

Notice how the return type defined by the variable `TYPE` is still interpolated, but everything inside the body is off limits.

You'll have to resort to a different mechanism to get your variable in there. You could leverage the fact that psql accepts a query through STDIN:

```
$ sed 's/:SRID/2056/' query.sql | psql
```